# message not triggered in websocket chat application while using differnt application

Tags: java, spring, websocket

I created one spring boot application, which holds controller and websocket configuration. And for testing I create html and angularjs file in same application.

If 2 different users login .. they can able to chat. Its working fine.

I create one web application with spring and add the html and angularjs page. So one user login in web application page and another user login through previous application (test) and try to chat.

User in web application cant receive any message, mean while user through test page can able receive the message.

my sample code :

```
package com.aghil.chat.controller;

import java.security.Principal;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.MessageMapping;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Payload;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessageHeaderAccessor;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import com.aghil.chat.dto.ChatMessageDto;

@Controller
public class ChatMessageController {

    @Autowired
    SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    @MessageMapping("/chat")
    public void greeting(Message<Object> message, @Payload ChatMessageDto chatMessage) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Stomp client called");
        Principal principal = message.getHeaders().get(SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.USER_HEADER, Principal.class);
        String authedSender = principal.getName();
        chatMessage.setSender(authedSender);
        String recipient = chatMessage.getRecipient();
        System.out.println("authedSender : "+authedSender +" --- recipient :: "+recipient);

        if (!authedSender.equals(recipient)) {
            template.convertAndSendToUser(authedSender, "/queue/messages", chatMessage);
        }

        template.convertAndSendToUser(recipient, "/queue/messages", chatMessage);
    }

}

JS:

 function connect() {
            var socket = new SockJS('/chat');
            stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
            stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
                setConnected(true);
                console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
                stompClient.subscribe('/user/queue/messages', function(greeting){
                    showMessage(greeting.body);
                });
            });
        }
 function sendMessage() {
            var recipient = document.getElementById('recipient').value;
            var message = document.getElementById('message').value;
            var date = new Date();
            var time = date.toISOString();

            stompClient.send("/app/chat", {}, JSON.stringify({ 'sender': '', 'recipient': recipient, 'message': message, 'time': time }));
        }



function showMessage(message) {
            var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(message);

            var response = document.getElementById('response');

            if(jsonResponse.message !== "New Chat Request") {
                var eachMgsDiv = document.createElement('div');

                eachMgsDiv.setAttribute('class','col-sm-12 ng-scope');

                var recipient = document.getElementById('recipient').value;

                if(jsonResponse.recipient === recipient) {
                    eachMgsDiv.innerHTML = myMgsTmpPrt1 + jsonResponse.sender + myMgsTmpPrt2  + myMgsTmpPrt3 + jsonResponse.message + myMgsTmpPrt4 + new Date(jsonResponse.time) + myMgsTmpPrt5;
                }
                else {
                    eachMgsDiv.innerHTML = othersMgsTmpPrt1 + jsonResponse.sender + othersMgsTmpPrt2 + othersMgsTmpPrt3 + jsonResponse.message + othersMgsTmpPrt4 + new Date(jsonResponse.time) + othersMgsTmpPrt5;
                }

                response.appendChild(eachMgsDiv);
            }
```

Comment: Can you provide any code samples?

Comment: Thanks for looking in to problem.. i paste my sample code here ..